# Javascript Object enumeration syntax

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var State = {
  WAITING: 1,
  READY: 2
}
```

and this object for getting texts for the state:

```
var Language = {
  States: {
    WAITING: "Waiting..",
    READY: "Ready!"
  }
}
```

I want to get the text directly from state like this:

```
var state = State.READY;

var statusText = Language.States[state];
```

for this to work I need, something like, this illegal syntax:

```
var Language = {
  States: {
    State.WAITING: "Waiting..",
    State.READY: "Ready!"
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work, what can I use to simply get the text from state variable?

Comment: There are existing questions about dynamic keys in object literals, many of which have noted the relevant change in ES6. Example: [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: [MDN - Object initializer - Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Ironic that your name is "facebook"; you might be interested in [keymirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keymirror). It was developed by facebook.

Comment: and marked as duplicate by a facebook employee lol

Comment: @FelixKling sure this is a duplicate in the narrow sense of "how to I specify a variable object key", but actually it's not in the broad sense of "how to I implement enums in JS". People coming from C etc. are use dto enums as a set of "names" that usually have integer values. The OP's issue is not actually that he wants syntax for variable property names, it's that he is thinking of enums like they exist In C, which made him think we wanted to be able to say `States: { State.WAITING: `. So I don't think it's a duplicate in that sense and should be reopened for good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. Just make your values be sensible instead of magic numbers. In this case, make them use strings that map to the key names that your other object(s) use, and done:

```
var States = {
  WAITING: "WAITING",
  READY: "READY"
}

var Language = {
  States: {
    WAITING: "Waiting..",
    READY: "Ready!"
  }
}
```

Voila:

```
var state = States.WAITING;
var label = Language.States[state]
```

And if those state numbers mean something, then make a lookup for them, too:

```
var responseCodes = {
  "0": "WAITING",
  "1": "READING",
  "403": "FORBIDDEN",
  ...
}
```

And then just chain your lookups:

```
...
var responseCode = whatever();
var state = responseCodes[responseCode];
var label = Language.State[state];
...
```

Comment: But why have a hash whose only job is to map strings to themselves? Instead of saying `state = States.WAITING`, it would be equivalent to just say `state = 'WAITING'`.

Comment: obviously? but the original question creates an extracted state, so it's trivial to bypass that, but let's keep it in the answer so that if that's actually necessary, there it is.

Answer (score 1):

You may be coming from a language background where enums are a collection of names that represent integer values. It's easier in JS to use strings for enum values, and then you can use them directly as keys to look up things in hashes, or use them directly in a `switch` statement, so you don't need the `State` variable at all. All you need is

```
var Language = {
  States: {
    WAITING: "Waiting..",
    READY: "Ready!"
  }
}

var state = 'READY';

var statusText = Language.States[state];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var State = {
  WAITING: 1,
  READY: 2
};

var Language = {
  States: {}
};

Language.States[State.WAITING] = "Waiting..";
//evaluated as, Language.States[1] = "Waiting..";
Language.States[State.READY] = "Ready!";

var state = State.READY;

var statusText = Language.States[state];

alert(statusText);
```

Comment: Code is good. Code with explanation is better.